# $1^2+17^2+19^2=3\cdot 7\cdot 31$

Tags: nt.number-theory

$1^2+17^2+19^2=3\cdot 7\cdot 31$.

$3$, $7$ and $31$ are the first three Mersenne primes

Let be $a$, $b$ and $c$ positive integers.

Let $M_n$ denote the n-th Mersenne prime.

Can be it proven that there are infinitely many positive a,b,c such that:

$a^2+b^2+c^2=P_n$, where $P_n$ is the product of the first $n$ Mersenne primes?

Comment: Note that your statement would imply that there are infinitely many Mersenne primes, which is an open problem. Bu per Geoff's logic, if there are infinitely many Mersenne primes, then your statement is true. So your statement is equivalent to their being infinitely many Mersenne primes.

Answer (score 7):

For $n \geq 3$, the product of the first $n$ Mersenne primes is congruent to $3 \times (-1)^{n-1},$ (mod $8$), since every Mersenne prime other than $3$ is congruent to $7$ (mod $8$).On the other hand, Legendre's three-square theorem asserts that the only positive integers which are not expressible as the sum of three integer squares are integers of the form $4^{a}(8b+7)$ with $a,b$ integers. No integer of the latter form is congruent to $\pm 3$ (mod $8$), so for $n \geq 3$, the product of the first $n$ Mersenne primes is expressible as the sum of three integer squares (but clearly, each such number is so expressible in only finitely many ways in this way).